# Combine Fuerte and Electric in one application

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, network, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I want to combine two computers in a ROS network. On one of them runs Fuerte, the other PC executes ROS Electric. I cannot implement a connection between both. Are there known problems with different ROS versions in this context?

In a pure Electric network the connection works well.

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47642/combine-fuerte-and-electric-in-one-application/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While it might be possible to set up communication between electric and fuerte nodes, this use case is not supported and definitely not recommended. Message definitions might have changed and you might run into all different kinds of bugs and problems.

Btw. please always tag your question appropriately to make sure the right people get notified.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-11-06**:
Thanks for this information !